# Justification paragraph in table cell using openxml 2.5

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, openxml

I try to add paragraph into table cell with center, but it does not works.
I do a lots of research on the internet, and stackoverflow as well, but no lucky.
1. Try to add center using Justification and add into paragraph, did not work
2. Try to add center using Justification and add into RunProperties also did not owk
Here is my code wrote in vb.net

```
Function SetFormatHeaderText(txt) As Paragraph
    Dim prg As Paragraph = New Paragraph()
    Dim run As New Run()

    Dim t As Text = New Text(txt)
    Dim rPr As RunProperties = New RunProperties()

    Dim fSize As FontSize = New FontSize() With {.Val = "22"}
    Dim fName As RunFonts = New RunFonts With {.Ascii = "Calibri"}
    'Dim jf As Justification = New Justification With {.Val = JustificationValues.Center}
    Dim b As Bold = New Bold()
    'rPr.Append(jf)
    'prg.AppendChild(Of Justification)(New Justification() With {.Val = JustificationValues.Center})

    rPr.Append(fSize)
    rPr.Append(fName)
    rPr.Append(b)

    run.Append(rPr)
    run.Append(t)

    prg.Append(run)

    Return prg
End Function
```

Here is the output for rpt.Append(jf)
Issue Date

Comment: Did you try opening a (small) sample document in the Open XML sDK Productivity Tool and look at the code that produces for generating the document? Right off-hand, I'd say you'd need to specify paragraph formatting (which Alignment is) in the ***Paragraph Properties*** ( `pPr`)

Comment: Thanks Cindy, I make it works

Answer (score 0):

I found solution and hope that can help other people who need center the table cell

```
Function SetFormatHeaderText(txt) As Paragraph

    'Create a paragraph
    Dim prg As Paragraph = New Paragraph()
    'Paragraph properties to format the text to center
    Dim prgP As ParagraphProperties = New ParagraphProperties()
    'Run the properties change
    Dim rPr As RunProperties = New RunProperties()
    'Run the all change
    Dim run As New Run()

    Dim t As Text = New Text(txt)

    Dim fSize As FontSize = New FontSize() With {.Val = "22"}
    Dim fName As RunFonts = New RunFonts With {.Ascii = "Calibri"}
    Dim jf As Justification = New Justification With {.Val = JustificationValues.Center}
    Dim b As Bold = New Bold()
    'Add center property for paragraph properties
    prgP.Append(jf)
    'Add paragraph properties to paragraph
    prg.Append(prgP)
    'Add text format using run properties
    rPr.Append(fSize)
    rPr.Append(fName)
    rPr.Append(b)

    'Run the text and run properties
    run.Append(rPr)
    run.Append(t)

    'Add the change back to paragraph
    prg.Append(run)

    Return prg
End Function
```